# VueJS - Unable to catch the axios error in Vue/CLI project

Tags: vue.js, axios

Hello i am trying to display a message whenever the API has any error, here $http is axios

The code is given Below:

**Case 1**

```
...
<span class="badge" id="disconnected" v-if="noerror" >{{noerror.name}}</span>
<span class="badge" id="disconnected" v-if="error" >{{error}}</span>
...
isData: false,
error: null,
noerror: null,
...
status(id) {
          this.$http.get(`/status_init/${id}`)
            .then(response => {
              this.noerror = response.data
              this.isData = true
            })
            .catch ((e) => {this.error = 'No data'})

      }
```

**Case 2**

```
    ...template remains same...

    status(id) {
      const self = this
          self.$http.get(`/status_init/${id}`, {
          headers : {
          'Authorization': process.env.Authorization
        })
            .then(response => {
              self.noerror = response.data
              self.isData = true
            })
             .catch ((e) => {self.error = 'No data'})
      }
```

If i do it like case 1 then the routes with 200 status is working absolutely fine but here the routes with some other status is not displaying anything. Thus in case 1 it shows `.then` part only. And in console if routes does not give 200 status then i get:

```
GET https://----URL----2 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) in console
```

If i do it like case 2 then the routes with 200 status and the routes with some other status are displaying `'No Data'`. Thus in case 2 it shows `.catch` part only. And in console for every routes I get:

```
GET https://----URL----2 422 unprocessable IN console
```

Case 1 is working fine for me as it is showing proper details for 200 Ok routes, but here only problem is that it does not show the .catch logic for status other than 200 and for me it throws 401 in case of error in routes rather than displaying 'No Data'

Please do help me, i want to catch and display message which ever the error code is. The error that i am getting currently in the postman:

[image]

Comment: How does your API throw an error? Can you show n your post?

Comment: Sure! i will update it

Comment: Are you sure that the request really threw an error? You need to make sure that the request is using 4XX or 5XX response codes. When viewed from the network tab in the chrome developer tools, the request will appear red.

Comment: Yeah i am sure it is throwing an error, because i checked it in postman, i have updated my question please check

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: You are only posting specific parts of your original code. It would be better if you can post the whole thing as I suspect that something else is causing this problem

Comment: Okay sure i will send you the CodeSandbox

Comment: Oops all are interlinked, and it becomes very huge!

Comment: What may be the reason you thing that its not showing the catch message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch the error as below logic. You need to use two variables. One is to keep track of the response and another is for keeping the data.

```js
...
isData: false,
noerror: null,
...

  status(id) {
    const self = this;
    self.$http.get(`/status_init/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': process.env.Authorization
        }).then(response => {
        self.noerror = response.data;
        self.isData = true;
      }).catch((e) => {
        self.noerror = 'No data';
        self.isData = false;
      })
    }
  }
```

```html
<span class="badge" v-if="isData">{{noerror.name}}</span>
<span class="badge" v-if="!isData">{{noerror}}</span>
```